# Bootstrap popover on flot graph

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, flot

I am trying to add popover on my graph. it is not working.

```js
var datasets = [{
  "label": "Amend Existing Report",
  "data": [{
    "0": 1446422400000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1447027200000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1447632000000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1448236800000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1448841600000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1449446400000,
    "1": 1
  }, {
    "0": 1450051200000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1450656000000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1451260800000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1451865600000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1452470400000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1453075200000,
    "1": 1
  }, {
    "0": 1453680000000,
    "1": 1
  }, {
    "0": 1454284800000,
    "1": 0
  }],
  "idx": 0
}, {
  "label": "Investigate Report Problem",
  "data": [{
    "0": 1446422400000,
    "1": 1
  }, {
    "0": 1447027200000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1447632000000,
    "1": 2
  }, {
    "0": 1448236800000,
    "1": 4
  }, {
    "0": 1448841600000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1449446400000,
    "1": 1
  }, {
    "0": 1450051200000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1450656000000,
    "1": 2
  }, {
    "0": 1451260800000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1451865600000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1452470400000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1453075200000,
    "1": 5
  }, {
    "0": 1453680000000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1454284800000,
    "1": 0
  }],
  "idx": 1
}, {
  "label": "New Request (One Off Report)",
  "data": [{
    "0": 1446422400000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1447027200000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1447632000000,
    "1": 1
  }, {
    "0": 1448236800000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1448841600000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1449446400000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1450051200000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1450656000000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1451260800000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1451865600000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1452470400000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1453075200000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1453680000000,
    "1": 1
  }, {
    "0": 1454284800000,
    "1": 0
  }],
  "idx": 2
}, {
  "label": "New Request (Regular Report)",
  "data": [{
    "0": 1446422400000,
    "1": 4
  }, {
    "0": 1447027200000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1447632000000,
    "1": 2
  }, {
    "0": 1448236800000,
    "1": 2
  }, {
    "0": 1448841600000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1449446400000,
    "1": 1
  }, {
    "0": 1450051200000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1450656000000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1451260800000,
    "1": 1
  }, {
    "0": 1451865600000,
    "1": 1
  }, {
    "0": 1452470400000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1453075200000,
    "1": 3
  }, {
    "0": 1453680000000,
    "1": 2
  }, {
    "0": 1454284800000,
    "1": 0
  }],
  "idx": 3
}, {
  "label": "Other",
  "data": [{
    "0": 1446422400000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1447027200000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1447632000000,
    "1": 2
  }, {
    "0": 1448236800000,
    "1": 4
  }, {
    "0": 1448841600000,
    "1": 2
  }, {
    "0": 1449446400000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1450051200000,
    "1": 2
  }, {
    "0": 1450656000000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1451260800000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1451865600000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1452470400000,
    "1": 3
  }, {
    "0": 1453075200000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1453680000000,
    "1": 3
  }, {
    "0": 1454284800000,
    "1": 0
  }],
  "idx": 4
}, {
  "label": "Special Events",
  "data": [{
    "0": 1446422400000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1447027200000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1447632000000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1448236800000,
    "1": 1
  }, {
    "0": 1448841600000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1449446400000,
    "1": 3
  }, {
    "0": 1450051200000,
    "1": 1
  }, {
    "0": 1450656000000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1451260800000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1451865600000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1452470400000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1453075200000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1453680000000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1454284800000,
    "1": 0
  }],
  "idx": 5
}];

var ticks = [];
for (var i = 0; i < datasets[0].data.length; i++) {
  ticks.push(datasets[0].data[i][0]);
}

var options = {
  "legend": {
    "position": "ne",
    "noColumns": 6
  },
  "yaxis": {
    "min": 0
  },
  "xaxis": {
    "mode": "time",
    "timeformat": "%d %b",
    //    "tickSize": [7, "day"],
    ticks: ticks,
    "min": 1446163200000,
    "max": 1454544000000 // 1454284800000
  },
  "grid": {
    "clickable": true,
    "hoverable": true
  },
  "series": {
    "stack": true,
    "bars": {
      "show": true,
      "barWidth": 181440000.00000003,
      align: 'center'
    }
  }
};

$.plot($('#CAGraph'), datasets, options);




$("#CAGraph").bind("plothover",function(event, pos, item) {

 if (item) {
//console.log(item);
   var epoch = new Date(item.datapoint[0]);
   var percent = item.datapoint[1].toFixed(0);
   $('#tooltip').attr("data-original-title", item.series.label);
   $('#tooltip').attr("data-content", (percent) + "<br>Total: " + item.datapoint[1]);
   $("#tooltip").popover("show");
   
   $("#tooltip").popover({
    html: true,
    title : function() {
             return $(".popover-title").html();
    },
    content : function() {
             return  $(".popover-content").html();
    }
    
   });
   $(".popover").css({
    top : item.pageY,
    left : item.pageX + 10
   });
   $(".popover.right>.arrow").css({
    top : "20%",
   });

  } else {
   $('#tooltip').attr("title","");
   $('#tooltip').attr("data-content", "");
   
   $("#tooltip").popover("hide");
  } 
  
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/flot/flot/master/jquery.flot.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/Codicode/flotanimator/master/jquery.flot.animator.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flot/0.8.3/jquery.flot.time.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flot/0.8.3/jquery.flot.stack.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flot.tooltip/0.8.5/jquery.flot.tooltip.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.11.2/moment.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha256-7s5uDGW3AHqw6xtJmNNtr+OBRJUlgkNJEo78P4b0yRw= sha512-nNo+yCHEyn0smMxSswnf/OnX6/KwJuZTlNZBjauKhTK0c+zT+q5JOCx0UFhXQ6rJR9jg6Es8gPuD2uZcYDLqSw==" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha256-KXn5puMvxCw+dAYznun+drMdG1IFl3agK0p/pqT9KAo= sha512-2e8qq0ETcfWRI4HJBzQiA3UoyFk6tbNyG+qSaIBZLyW9Xf3sWZHN/lxe9fTh1U45DpPf07yj94KsUHHWe4Yk1A==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<div id="choices_CAGraph"></div>
<div id="CAGraph" style="width:910px;height:400px"></div>
<div id=tooltip class="popover" role="tooltip"><div class="arrow"></div><h3 class="popover-title"></h3><div class="popover-content"></div></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, any solution has to take into account the async behavior of Bootstrap's popover functionality as [Raidri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2610249/raidri) correctly stated a couple of comments ago. Plus it has to take into account the fact that the `plothover` event is going to be firing a lot faster than the async popover show/hide calls finish. In other words, you are going to have to pay special attention to the *state* of the system.

This led me to the understanding that creating the popover object over and over again as part of the hover event handler was a no-no. It has to be created *once* and then just shown and hidden.

I note also that in your latest code you again ignored my previous point that the title and content properties are either strings *or* functions that return a string. You are returning jQuery objects from yours -- wrong.

First up I created a new jQuery function. This would help me maintain the state needed in a closure, including the popover object.

```
$.fn.popoverTooltip = function (selector, popoverSelector) {
  // the rest of the code forming a nice closure
}
$.plot('#CAGraph', datasets, options);
$("#tooltip").popoverTooltip("#CAGraph", ".popover");
```

As part of this enclosed code, I created some local variables at the top:

```
var barIdShown = null;
var chart = $(selector);
var tooltip = $(this);

var popoverProcessor = function () {
  // mysterious code maintaining state
}();
```

And then a new object called `popoverProcessor` (code to be shown in a moment) that was going to do most of the actual work, and maintain state.

After that code, I create the actual popover and bound some event handlers. First: I need to know *when* the popover hide/show functionality *actually* finishes so I added handlers to the relevant BS popover events. Second: I bound a handler to the `plothover` event to process showing or hiding the tooltip.

```
//create popover
tooltip.popover({
  html: true,
  title : popoverProcessor.getTitle,
  content : popoverProcessor.getContent
});

// bind events to know when shown or hidden
tooltip.on("hidden.bs.popover", popoverProcessor.hideDone);
tooltip.on("shown.bs.popover", popoverProcessor.showDone);

// bind hover event to chart
chart.bind("plothover", function(event, pos, item) {
  var thisBarId;
  if (item) {
    thisBarId = seriesIndex * 10000 + dataIndex;
    if (thisBarId !== barIdShown) {
      if (barIdShown) {
        popoverProcessor.hide();
      }
      popoverProcessor.setItem(item);
      popoverProcessor.show();
      barIdShown = thisBarId;
    }
  }
  else {
    if (barIdShown) {
      popoverProcessor.hide();
      barIdShown = null;
    }
  }
});
```

Notice first that I use functions inside my `popoverProcessor` to return the title and content of the tooltip. Then in order to know if the cursor hovers over another bar segment without moving outside the bar, I create a special "bar identifier". (If it changes I hide the popover, before re-showing it.) It's all nicely "synchronous" inside this handler, note; the async part is handled inside this mysterious `popoverProcessor` object.

```
var popoverProcessor = function () {
  var item = null;
  var state = "hidden";
  var taskQueue = [];
  var showPopover = function () {
    tooltip.popover("show");
    $(popoverSelector).css({
      top : item.pageY,
      left : item.pageX + 10
    });
    $(".popover.right > .arrow").css({
      top : "20%",
    });      
    state = "showing";
  };
  var hidePopover = function () {
    tooltip.popover("hide");
    state = "hiding";
  };
  var processNextTask = function () {
    var task;
    if (taskQueue.length > 0) {
      task = taskQueue.shift();
      if (task === "show") {
        showPopover();
      }
      else {
        hidePopover();
      }      
    }
  };

  return {
    setItem: function (newItem) { item = newItem; },
    getTitle: function () { 
      if (item) {
        return item.series.label; 
      }
      return "unknown item";
    },
    getContent: function () { 
      var percent;
      if (item) {
        percent = item.datapoint[1].toFixed(0);
        return percent.toString() + "<br />Total: " + item.datapoint[1];
      }
      return "unknown item";
    },
    hideDone: function () {
      state = "hidden";
      processNextTask();
    },
    showDone: function () {
      state = "shown";
      processNextTask();
    },
    hide: function () {
      if (state === "shown") {
        hidePopover();
      }
      else {
        taskQueue.push("hide");
      }
    },
    show: function () {
      if (state === "hidden") {
        showPopover();
      }
      else {
        taskQueue.push("show");
      }
    }
  };
}();
```

The public object has a set of methods. You can set the item being processed, you can get the title and content for the popover, you can signal that the popover has shown (or has been hidden) and you can ask for the popover to be shown or hidden.

The processor maintains the current state of the popover object. These are: "hidden", "showing", "shown", and "hiding". If you call `hide()` and the state is "shown", the code immediately calls the internal function `hidePopover` to start hiding the popover, otherwise an item is added to a task queue to indicate that the popover should be hidden when possible. A similar thing happens if you call `show()`.

The fun stuff happens in the event handlers `showDone()` and `hideDone()`. This is where the next task is popped off the task queue and is processed. Using this task queue, I am maintaining the sequence of hide/show calls in the Bootstrap async environment, ensuring that a new display state change is only initiated when the previous one has completed.

Note also that it's when `.popover("show")` is called that the title and content for the tooltip are actually calculated via the functions provided.

No doubt this code could be refactored a bit to be made simpler, but I'm done.

Answer (score 1):

The id for the tooltip div is wrong in the HTML: `tootltip` instead of `tooltip`.

And in the JavaScript the id for the chart container is wrong: `$("CAGraph").bind("plothover", ...` instead of `$("#CAGraph").bind("plothover",...`

After fixing these two errors, the popover shows but without content.
**Update:** I got the popover to show some content, but could not get it to work consistently. This is probably because the [popover show method is asnyc](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers-methods):

> **`.popover('show')`**
>
> Reveals an element's popover. **Returns to the caller before the popover has actually been shown** (i.e. before the `shown.bs.popover` event occurs). This is considered a "manual" triggering of the popover. Popovers whose both title and content are zero-length are never displayed.

Falling back to manually generating the tooltip however works fine. See the updated code snippet:

```js
var datasets = [{
  "label": "Amend Existing Report",
  "data": [{
    "0": 1446422400000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1447027200000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1447632000000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1448236800000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1448841600000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1449446400000,
    "1": 1
  }, {
    "0": 1450051200000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1450656000000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1451260800000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1451865600000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1452470400000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1453075200000,
    "1": 1
  }, {
    "0": 1453680000000,
    "1": 1
  }, {
    "0": 1454284800000,
    "1": 0
  }],
  "idx": 0
}, {
  "label": "Investigate Report Problem",
  "data": [{
    "0": 1446422400000,
    "1": 1
  }, {
    "0": 1447027200000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1447632000000,
    "1": 2
  }, {
    "0": 1448236800000,
    "1": 4
  }, {
    "0": 1448841600000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1449446400000,
    "1": 1
  }, {
    "0": 1450051200000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1450656000000,
    "1": 2
  }, {
    "0": 1451260800000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1451865600000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1452470400000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1453075200000,
    "1": 5
  }, {
    "0": 1453680000000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1454284800000,
    "1": 0
  }],
  "idx": 1
}, {
  "label": "New Request (One Off Report)",
  "data": [{
    "0": 1446422400000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1447027200000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1447632000000,
    "1": 1
  }, {
    "0": 1448236800000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1448841600000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1449446400000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1450051200000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1450656000000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1451260800000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1451865600000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1452470400000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1453075200000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1453680000000,
    "1": 1
  }, {
    "0": 1454284800000,
    "1": 0
  }],
  "idx": 2
}, {
  "label": "New Request (Regular Report)",
  "data": [{
    "0": 1446422400000,
    "1": 4
  }, {
    "0": 1447027200000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1447632000000,
    "1": 2
  }, {
    "0": 1448236800000,
    "1": 2
  }, {
    "0": 1448841600000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1449446400000,
    "1": 1
  }, {
    "0": 1450051200000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1450656000000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1451260800000,
    "1": 1
  }, {
    "0": 1451865600000,
    "1": 1
  }, {
    "0": 1452470400000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1453075200000,
    "1": 3
  }, {
    "0": 1453680000000,
    "1": 2
  }, {
    "0": 1454284800000,
    "1": 0
  }],
  "idx": 3
}, {
  "label": "Other",
  "data": [{
    "0": 1446422400000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1447027200000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1447632000000,
    "1": 2
  }, {
    "0": 1448236800000,
    "1": 4
  }, {
    "0": 1448841600000,
    "1": 2
  }, {
    "0": 1449446400000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1450051200000,
    "1": 2
  }, {
    "0": 1450656000000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1451260800000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1451865600000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1452470400000,
    "1": 3
  }, {
    "0": 1453075200000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1453680000000,
    "1": 3
  }, {
    "0": 1454284800000,
    "1": 0
  }],
  "idx": 4
}, {
  "label": "Special Events",
  "data": [{
    "0": 1446422400000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1447027200000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1447632000000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1448236800000,
    "1": 1
  }, {
    "0": 1448841600000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1449446400000,
    "1": 3
  }, {
    "0": 1450051200000,
    "1": 1
  }, {
    "0": 1450656000000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1451260800000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1451865600000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1452470400000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1453075200000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1453680000000,
    "1": 0
  }, {
    "0": 1454284800000,
    "1": 0
  }],
  "idx": 5
}];

var ticks = [];
for (var i = 0; i < datasets[0].data.length; i++) {
  ticks.push(datasets[0].data[i][0]);
}

var options = {
  "legend": {
    "position": "ne",
    "noColumns": 6
  },
  "yaxis": {
    "min": 0
  },
  "xaxis": {
    "mode": "time",
    "timeformat": "%d %b",
    //    "tickSize": [7, "day"],
    ticks: ticks,
    "min": 1446163200000,
    "max": 1454544000000 // 1454284800000
  },
  "grid": {
    "clickable": true,
    "hoverable": true
  },
  "series": {
    "stack": true,
    "bars": {
      "show": true,
      "barWidth": 181440000.00000003,
      align: 'center'
    }
  }
};

$.plot($('#CAGraph'), datasets, options);


$("#CAGraph").bind("plothover", function(event, pos, item) {
  if (item) {
    var epoch = new Date(item.datapoint[0]);
    var percent = item.datapoint[1] - item.datapoint[2];
    $("#tooltip").html(item.series.label + " " + (percent) + "<br>Total: " + item.datapoint[1]).css({
      top: item.pageY - 25,
      left: item.pageX + 10,
      padding: 5
    }).fadeIn(200);
  } else {
    $("#tooltip").hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/flot/flot/master/jquery.flot.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/Codicode/flotanimator/master/jquery.flot.animator.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flot/0.8.3/jquery.flot.time.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flot/0.8.3/jquery.flot.stack.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flot.tooltip/0.8.5/jquery.flot.tooltip.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.11.2/moment.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha256-7s5uDGW3AHqw6xtJmNNtr+OBRJUlgkNJEo78P4b0yRw= sha512-nNo+yCHEyn0smMxSswnf/OnX6/KwJuZTlNZBjauKhTK0c+zT+q5JOCx0UFhXQ6rJR9jg6Es8gPuD2uZcYDLqSw=="
crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha256-KXn5puMvxCw+dAYznun+drMdG1IFl3agK0p/pqT9KAo= sha512-2e8qq0ETcfWRI4HJBzQiA3UoyFk6tbNyG+qSaIBZLyW9Xf3sWZHN/lxe9fTh1U45DpPf07yj94KsUHHWe4Yk1A==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div id="choices_CAGraph"></div>
<div id="CAGraph" style="width:910px;height:400px"></div>
<div id=tooltip class="popover" role="tooltip">
  <div class="arrow"></div>
  <h3 class="popover-title"></h3>
  <div class="popover-content"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: updated the spelling. the content does not show. also can i add positioning the way I would have with div element. see the commented out part in js

Comment: Here's what I found after 10 minutes' work. `.popover("show")`, not `.show()`. `.popover("hide")`, not `.hide()`. `title` and `content` properties are either strings or a function that returns a string, not what you have. I'm not even sure you can have your own content like you're trying. You're going to have to do something else about showing this popover tooltip: the `plothover` event fires a lot of times very quickly (maybe a `alreadyDisplayed` property somewhere?). I'd also get used to debugging JavaScript.

Comment: I have updated my code. if you take a look it does not change the title also  it shows HTML tags and the position is always top left corner

Comment: I saw that, but all these problems don't happen with the manual tooltip instead of the popover.

Comment: I have been using the manual tooltip all this time, just wanted to try something different